# Grid Layout make elements evenly spaced

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make GUI using gridlayout and I want every GUI element rows to be evenly spaced such that they fill whole screen, but following xml code causes the first three rows to cover only 30% of screen and last button covers 70 % screen with margins. What caused this problem as I have already specified row count to be 4 ?

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="......"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:columnCount="2">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mobile"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Email"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Password"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:onClick="Onclick_log"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `android:layout_rowWeight="1"` parameter with all views.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `ListAdapter` to populate items of a `GridView` according to google documentation for [GridView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) :

> **GridView** is a ViewGroup that displays items in a two-dimensional,
>   scrollable grid. The grid items are automatically inserted to the
>   layout using a **ListAdapter**.

So you cannot add items manually inside a `GridView`.
If you want to have for rows with same height you can use something like a `LinearLayout` with and set `layout_height` of its children to `0dp` and their `layout_weight` to an equal value like 1. Here is a sample which got 4 rows and each row is a `LinearLayout` but the trick is setting their height to `0dp` and using equal weight for all of them:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <!-- row 1-->
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <!-- row 2-->
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <!-- row 3-->
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <!-- row 4-->
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```